# Accessing Cookies in View value null MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies

So I really stumped with cookies right now and I'm not exactly sure whats going on. I saw a lot of cookie questions regarding losing values of cookies and I've tried almost copying exact same code but it still doesn't seem to resolve any of the issues.

Here is the code I use to set the cookie.

```
HttpCookie cookie = Response.Cookies["Name"];
if (cookie != null)
{
cookie.Value = user.LastName + " " + user.FirstName;
cookie.Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(1);
Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);
}
else
{
cookie.Name = "Name";
cookie.Value = user.LastName + " " + user.FirstName;
cookie.Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(1);
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
}


return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

Currently I'm debugging at Home/Index to check the values of the cookie before it gets to the view to see what is in the cookie.

One strange note is that when I check the content of the cookie the values are there but the Expire date is reset to 1/1/0001 right after I redirect from creating the cookie. I don't understand why does it reset it... or am I not setting/adding the cookies properly?

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["Name"];
ViewBag.Name = cookie.Value;
return View();
}
public ActionResult About()
{
HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["Name"];
return View();
}
```

The issue is that the Cookie value is there before I return to the view but once I get to the view and try to access it directly from the view with.

```
@Response.Cookies["Name"].Value
```

The moment I get to the view the cookie values are null, expiration time gets change to when the browser is close when I check the cookie in the setting of chrome.

I read on some other articles it had something to do with the way I am redirecting, but I tried using response.redirect but it didn't seem to fix the issue. Can anyone point me in the right direction for handling this?

Comment: You really *shouldn't* be accessing `Response` in the view.  (Nor in the controller, but let's take this one step at a time.)  You're already setting the value to `ViewBag.Name`, why not use `ViewBag.Name` in the view?  Or even better, set the value to a property on a model and bind the view to that model?

Comment: I was testing to basically put the users first/last name a div at the top on my _Layout.cshtml. If I use the ViewBag it would only work on one redirect the second time I try to access the cookie it is gone. I haven't tried binding it to a model as I initially just thought of cookies at the start.

Comment: `ViewBag` is just for the view that's about to be rendered, yes.  In the event of a redirect, that causes the client to make another request to another action.  In that action you would again prepare the view, by constructing a view model and/or `ViewBag` values.  If the cookie has been set then it will continue to be available in other controller actions.

Comment: have you tried setting the Response cookie in your controller? use this method `Response.SetCookie(cookie)` see if it's available in your View then?

Comment: @David The weird thing is the cookie is still exist but its expire date and value. I can still access the cookie but I don't understand why the content are being lost.

Comment: @Madullah I tried that method it does the same thing as Request.Cookies.Set(), data is being lost as I move from the initial creation/setting of the cookie.

Comment: @David: Why shouldn't you access the Response in the controller? Where/how would you set a cookie in that case?

Comment: @DaveParsons: The controller shouldn't be coupled to the HTTP context.  Abstract the storage of data behind a (mockable) object and couple that object to the HTTP context (cookies, session, etc.).  The controller can fetch that object from a factory or, better yet, require it as a parameter.  Then you can isolate the controller for testing without requiring an active web server.